# Cshtml trouble ASP.NET version declaration

Tags: xml, razor

How to I specify the version of ASP.NET I'm using in my .cshtml file? The web browser complained about it when I didn't and when I went to microsofts page to look at the problem I created a web.config file with the text

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <appsettings>
        <add key="webPages:Version" value="2.0" />
    </appsettings>
</configuration>
```

just like they said I should and now it says I have an error the code.
Saying that I miss a section declaration on the  line.

Full web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

    <appsettings>
        <add key="webPages:Version" value="2.0" />
    </appsettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: FYI, You're missing the starting `<configuration>` tag below the `<?xml` line. (though I think you've misunderstood what the browser's complaining about. there should be no need to put the language version on the page)

Comment: That's the code snippet that I found on Microsofts support page. I'll include my full web.config in the question